# Replace default placeholder after form submit

Tags: javascript, replace, default, placeholder

How can I replace the default placeholder in a form (using JQuery or JavaScript) with the submitted value? Thank you!

Here is a sample code:

```
<form name="" id="RegForm" method="post" action="">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="260" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" height="45" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text" placeholder="Your Username here" style="background:url(img/bg_text.png) no-repeat;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="120" height="50" valign="middle"><input type="image" id="submitbtn" src="img/but_register.png" class="submit" onclick="checkPreReg()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
   function checkPreReg() { 
    var form = $("#RegForm");
    var u = $("#username", form).val();
    $('#username',form).attr('placeholder',u);
}
</script>
```

It doesn't work at all. I tried other scripts but the value goes back to the default Placeholder after the new one appears briefly.

Comment: I think putting it as the placeholder would be confusing, better to put it as the default value.

Comment: I won't mind using "value" instead of "Placeholder", as long as I get the functionality, which is: a) the field tells what to enter (i.e. Username) b) When the user clicks in the field, the default text disappears c) When the user submits the form, the field shows what the user entered. Thank you, Rob!

Comment: An input type image is a submit button. The form is submitting, refreshing the page so you see the original form. Do not over use placeholders, and don't use them instead of an appropriate label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this question might need some clarification, however I will give it a shot.

if you mean:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="default_placeholder" />
```

Then I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#FORM').submit(function(){
    $('#INPUT_ID').attr('placeholder','new text here');
  });
});
```

Comment: @VincentHirth—it "works" but not as you expect, you just don't see the result because the form submits.